# st_is_within_distance to produce a value?

Tags: r

I am using st_join with the join=st_is_within_distance to match a dataframe with multipolygons to one with points. I want the joined file to note just how far away the matches were, so if the polygon picks up 20 points within the the 50' distance buffer, I could then sort by which of those points was closest to the polygon. Is that possible?

Code below:

```
combined<- st_join(df_poly, df_points, join=st_is_within_distance, dist = 50, left = TRUE)
```